# The boundary of a unbounded simply connected planar domain

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $D$ be a unbounded simply connected planar open domain. Let $\partial D$ be its boundary. The question is the following:
Can $\partial D$ have a compact component?

Comment: It depends on what "component" means. Do you mean "path-connected component" or "connected component"? In the first case the answer is yes, in the second - no.

Comment: I think component always means connected component，otherwise one should say path component. Why the answer is no？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $D\subset R^n$ is an open unbounded connected subset (a domain) whose boundary has a compact connected component. Then $E=R^n\setminus D$ has at least 2 connected components. Now, it follows from the Alexander duality that $H_{n-1}(D)\cong \tilde{H}^0(E)$ (the right hand side is the Chech cohomology). Hence, $H_{n-1}(D)$ has rank at least 1. In your case $n=2$ and the Hurewicz theorem implies that $\pi_1(D)$ is nontrivial. Contradiction.

In dimension 2 one can give a proof avoiding (co)homology, but I prefer this argument as more general.

Comment: This is a cool answer! (though of course you realize it is almost certainly useless to the OP, given how the question is tagged)

Comment: @JesseMadnick: Yes, and it was intentional on my part. If it is a homework problem from the complex analysis class then it is totally useless, but it might be useful for somebody more advanced.

Comment: @studiosus： Thanks for your answer. But what I really want to know is why the existence of compact component of $\partial D$ implies E is not connected.